# How to loop through (none, 256) shape tensor array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to write a  custom loss function to a Keras model. This loss function takes in the prediction and suppresses all the predictions except the highest one to zero. Something like this:

```
  def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    s=tf.shape(y_pred)
    loop=tf.unstack(y_pred)   
    th=[tf.math.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in loop]
    output=tf.zeros([len(loop),len(anchor_list)])
    y_pred_in=tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(output,[[i,th[i]] for i in loop],[y_pred[i,th[i]] for i in loop])
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    loss=cce(y_true,y_pred)
    return loss
```

I realized that while doing so I have to take care of batch size as well. For this, I want to create lists and arrays according to the shape of the prediction tensor. I found out that we cannot iterate over a tensor. So, I unstacked the tensor. However, get the following error:

```
 shape=tf.unstack(y_pred)

    ValueError: Cannot infer argument `num` from the shape (None, None)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: In TensorFlow, we do not have to use loops of iterate over tensors except few very rare cases. For example, do `th = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)` instead of first 3 rows of your function. Use any TensorFlow guides.

Comment: How do I scatter_nd_update the th element of the zeros array without using loop in line 5? @AlexeyTochin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This loss function takes in the prediction and suppresses all the predictions except the highest one to zero

I think this can easily be solved with `tf.where`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]

def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):    
    max_pred_value = tf.reduce_max(y_pred)
    y_pred_new = tf.where(tf.not_equal(y_pred, max_pred_value), tf.zeros_like(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32), max_pred_value)
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    tf.print('y_pred_new -->', y_pred_new)
    return cce(y_true, y_pred_new)

tf.print('loss -->', loss_function(y_true, y_pred))
```

```
y_pred_new --> [[0 0.95 0]
                [0 0 0]]
loss --> nan
```

But as you can see, converting almost all values to zero will lead to  `nan` loss values.

**Update 1**:
Try something like this if you want the max value across the second dimension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]

def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_shape = tf.shape(y_pred)   
    max_values = tf.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=1)
    max_values = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(max_values, repeats = y_pred_shape[1]), y_pred_shape)
    y_pred_new = tf.where(tf.not_equal(y_pred, max_values), tf.zeros_like(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32), max_values)
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    tf.print('y_pred_new -->', y_pred_new)
    return cce(y_true, y_pred_new)

tf.print('loss -->', loss_function(y_true, y_pred))
```

```
y_pred_new --> [[0 0.95 0]
 [0 0.8 0]]
loss --> 8.0590477
```

Comment: Hello @ALone, thank you for your answer. I meant reducing the element except for the max for each prediction i.e each axis to zero, not everything else zero. So, the output must be                                            y_pred_new---> [ [0,0.95,0] [0,0.8,0]]

Comment: So, the output must be y_pred_new---> [ [0,0.95,0] [0,0.8,0]]

Answer (score 0):

you can get a list representation of a tensor by using

```
list_from_tensor = list(tenor.numpy())
```

you can convert the list back to a tensor by using

```
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_from_tensor, dtype=tf.float32) #  tensor of floats
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_from_tensor, dtype=tf.int32) # tensor of integers
```

Here a [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes) to a website where all possible types are listed

Comment: Since it is a custom loss function to the Keras it works in graph mode. So, .numpy () does not work here. Is there any other way? @gerda